# php yii framework booking system ... algorithm

Tags: php, yii

i have   booking system
and i have table called 
**(Reserve) ->  ( id -  start_time  - finish_time -  place_id)**
and i have Form that user  enter **( start_time - finish_time  )**

What the algorithm that help me  to  prevent any re  duplicated reserve
OR : how  can i check ?

i can use  Helped  by (user:tinybyte)

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('start_time' , $model->start , $model->finish);
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('finish_time' , $model->start , $model->finish , 'OR');
```

but if user reserve from 1:9  and database get  3:5  it can also true
how can i prevent that?

Comment: use a validator in the model to check if a row exist for the same values OR override the `beforeSave()` function of the model and check if the row exist then `addError()` to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $connection = Yii::app()->db;</i>
    $command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (START_DATE between '.$start.' AND '.$end.')
    OR (END_DATE between '.$start.' AND '.$end.')
    OR (START_DATE >= '.$start.' AND END_DATE <= '.$end.')
    OR (START_DATE <= '.$start.' AND END_DATE >= '.$end.')');
    $row = $command->queryRow();
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You must prepare parameters. EG

$command->bindValue(":start", $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Answer (score 0):

you can check that there is no other record between start and finish time

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('start_time' , $model->start , $model->finish);
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('finish_time' , $model->start , $model->finish , 'OR');
```

if there are records with this criteria, then its duplicate

Comment: thx 4 u r reply >>> u mean if (empty($model))  i will make reserve ?

Comment: i want ask u about 1 case if i have already reserve  from  day  3:5   and user want  from  1:9    these code work in this case?

Comment: in this scenario overlapping dates will also get caught!

Comment: do you store datetime like '2010-01-01' or timestamp?

Comment: then if you also check with hours and minutes, it will be more accurate